# AVERAGE TOTALYTD gives incorrect result. Power BI DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I need to calculate `Average Year To Date` for `Closed` claims only.
If I use `FILTER` function then it gives me the correct result: $3,507.74

```
AVG_YTD_Indemn_Closed =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( fact_Losses[PaidIdemnity] ),
    FILTER (
        fact_Losses,
        fact_Losses[DateEntered].[Year] = YEAR ( TODAY () )
            && fact_Losses[ClaimStatus] = "Closed"
    )
)
```

[image]

But if I use `TOTALYTD` function then for some reason I got different result $4,702.31:

```
AVG_YTD_Indemn_Closed1 =
CALCULATE (
    TOTALYTD ( AVERAGE ( fact_Losses[PaidIdemnity] ), dim_Date[Date] ),
    fact_Losses[ClaimStatus] = "Closed"
)
```

[image]

Why such a big difference? How function `TOTALYTD` calculates the result that its different from `FILTER`?

Comment: Is `dim_Date` related to `fact_Losses` on `[DateEntered] <--- [Date]`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right direction. I look at the source code and found out that DateEntered need some additional logic. After modifying it I got the right number.  Thank you

Comment: Glad that worked. I started writing a reply before asking that, so I went ahead and posted anyway as it may be useful for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](https://dax.guide/totalytd/),

```
TOTALYTD (
    <EXPRESSION>,
    <DATES>
    [, <FILTER>]
    [, <YEARENDDATE>]
)
```

is equivalent to

```
CALCULATE (
    <EXPRESSION>,
    DATESYTD ( <DATES> [, <YEARENDDATE>] )
    [, <FILTER>]
)
```

So your `TOTALYTD` measure is equivalent to

```
AVG_YTD_Indemn_Closed1 =
CALCULATE (
    CALCULATE(
        AVERAGE ( fact_Losses[PaidIdemnity] ),
        DATESYTD( dim_Date[Date] )
    ),
    fact_Losses[ClaimStatus] = "Closed"
)
```

If you get your date relationship straightened out, I'd recommend this version since `TOTALYTD` can't accommodate additional filters you might need in the future, as noted [here](https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2018/08/10/the-hidden-secrets-of-totalytd/):

```
AVG_YTD_Indemn_Closed1 =
CALCULATE (
    AVERAGE ( fact_Losses[PaidIdemnity] ),
    DATESYTD( dim_Date[Date] ),
    fact_Losses[ClaimStatus] = "Closed"
)
```